# Django: convert cURL to python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have cURL code that I need to convert to python code using requests library. I want to use this inside django backend software.
I tried several ways but I am getting some erros. Can someone help me with this?
Here is the cURL code:

```
    curl -XPOST -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H
'X-Client-Id: asdf1234' -H 'X-Client-Secret: qwer9876' -d '{
"planId":"BASIC", "planName":"Basic subscription plan", "amount":12,
"intervalType":"week", "intervals":2,"description":"This is the standard plan
for our services"}' 'https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/subscription-plans'
```

Comment: "I tried several ways but I am getting some erro[r]s"—what did you try? What were the errors? Please read [ask] and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future, you can use a handy converter like [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-Client-Id': 'asdf1234',
    'X-Client-Secret': 'qwer9876',
}

data = '{"planId":"BASIC", "planName":"Basic subscription plan", "amount":12,"intervalType":"week", "intervals":2,"description":"This is the standard planfor our services"}'

response = requests.post('https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/subscription-plans', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: I tried this. When I print the response.text I am getting this message {"status":"ERROR","subCode":"400","message":"Invalid JSON in request body"}

Comment: That's probably because you didn't delete the \n. It returns {"status":"ERROR","subCode":"401","message":"Authentication Failure"}
 for me. @sreekanthkura7

Comment: I did delete \n. You are getting that error message because client-ID and secret that i mentioned here are not correct.

Comment: Yes I can tell. That error is not because of my code. @sreekanthkura7 . You should just copy my answer exactly and it will work.